# Gcc pure/const functions and longjmp

Tags: c, gcc, constants, setjmp

Suppose I have a C function that otherwise meets the criteria to be annotated with GCC's `__attribute__((pure))` or `__attribute__((const))`, *except* that for certain input parameters, the function might do a `longjmp` or an `abort` or something of that sort, instead of returning. So it wouldn't be what you'd ordinarily call a "pure" function. Still, if GCC is only using these annotations to decide when the return result of the function can be cached and reused, then plausibly one might still apply these annotations to such a function. If it *does* return, the function can be assumed to be a side-effect-free, pure result of its arguments (plus perhaps global state, depending on whether we're annotating with `pure` or `const`).

Does anyone have experience or knowledge about whether these annotations can be applied in such cases? (I'm interested in what can be relied on to work, not just what happens to work in some setups or with some compilation flags.)

Comment: The most relevant other question I've found is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6867696/272427).

Comment: In Haskell, all functions are pure, but may throw exceptions which are caught in the non pure IO monad.  As long as the generation of the exception is a function of the arguments, I don't see any problem with what you are doing. Of course, if you call the function and don't use its result, but the function would have generated an exception, it may or may not happen depending upon whether the compiler optimizes out the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) specifically mentions "functions with infinite loops" as examples of non-pure functions, so I think it's fair to say that you can't *rely* on good behavior when a function marked `pure` doesn't return. And since `const` is described as a stricter version of it, the same presumably goes for it as well.

> […] if GCC is only using these annotations to decide when the return result of the function can be cached and reused […]

According the same documentation, pure functions can be subject to "common subexpression elimination and loop optimization". I'm not sure exactly what those can cover. For example, if "loop optimization" includes the compiler being willing to reorder statements in order to factor a pure function *out* of a loop — that is, if something like

```
while (...) {
    ...;
    tmp = my_pure_function(17);
    ...;
}
```

could be converted to something like

```
tmp = my_pure_function(17);
while (...) {
    ...;
}
```

— then obviously annotating a `longjmp`-ing function with `__attribute__((pure))` could cause some code to not get executed that otherwise would have been.

(And — I'm really not sure — but I think the existence of `__attribute__((const))` kind of suggests that the compiler *is* willing to perform these sorts of reordering optimizations. Because the obvious difference between `pure` and `const` is that `const` functions can be reordered more freely, whereas `pure` functions can't be reordered across (potential) modifications of global variables. But that's just inference on my part, and I could be totally off.)

Answer (score 1):

Pure functions cannot reasonably lack a return type. Given that abort never returns, it seems to me that specifying a function that might not return as 'pure' is stretching it a bit. Because longjmp has side effects and a pure function shouldn't have any, your function sounds like a poor candidate for the pure attribute.

If you specify the const attribute for a function it may be reordered. If you then longjmp or abort, you may find yourself jumping or aborting before another function where order is important. This could cause undefined behavior and sounds like a nightmare to maintain.

Using these attributes in the given case may have undefined behavior. If you're looking for something that will work in all situations then I'd avoid these attributes on that function.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're probably right. The only thing I wanted to question concerned "Pure functions cannot reasonably lack a return type." Sure, that's true, but why do you say it? In the cases I'm imagining, the functions will have a clear return type, determined by what they return when they do return.

Comment: @dubiousjim I'll try and clarify: having a return type indicates that the function will return something. The problem with longjmp and abort is that they never return. If the compiler optimises the function on the assumption that it has a return type and therefore will return something, what will it do when it doesn't (eg, it longjmps or aborts)? To the best of my knowledge, that's not defined.

Comment: Good, I'm glad you articulated this. It's something I also worried about.